# How to establish a connection from a wxpython desktop app to a remote msyql database?

Tags: python, mysql, wxpython

I'm writing a desktop app in wxpython.  For simplicity sake let's say it's a just a frame with a button in it.  When someone clicks that button a record inserted into a remote mysql table with the public ip from which the click was made from.

```
CREATE TABLE clicks(
click_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ip_address VARCHAR(128),
exec_datetime DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(click_id)
)
```

What is the best method to establish a connection to a remote mysql database and insert a record from this desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to wrap your mysql calls in a web service (API).  The clients would then make web requests to your webservice through http/s

creating a web service would allow you to control authorization/authentication of your clients. (the wxpython app)

This can also be good because almost always port 80/443 (http/https) are open.  If you connect directly to your mysql database using python, there could be possiblity that port is not open.  Also, by using a webservice you can better throttle/control requests to your database,  It gives you an additional place to cache frequently used data, that a direct connection might not facilitate.